# Full Calendar Week Display Vertical View

Tags: jquery, html, fullcalendar

For the Latest version of full calendar version  how to get vertical view of the week tab.

i.e. instead of showing the days in columns, i need to show them in rows (Basic Week Mode )

so its the change in html i want which is done through jquery in the calendar plugin.

Below are the details of Full Calendar i am using:

```
/*!
 * FullCalendar v2.1.1
 * Docs & License: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/
 * (c) 2013 Adam Shaw
 */
```

so the view appears something like this:

```
sun 12/10/14
------------

mon 13/10/14
------------
event 1

tue 14/10/14
------------

event 1

wed 15/10/14
------------

event 1

fri 16/10/14
------------

event 1

sat 17/10/14
------------

event 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't exist as of v2.1.1 though it has often been requested. You could take a look at [my fork](https://github.com/samedii/fullcalendar) which does approximately what you are asking for. The view is called `listView`.

Note that some functionality is not supported (like dragging).

You can add your voice to the [discussion on code.google](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=289&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars).

Here's a picture of how the list view looks:
[image]

Comment: Thank you @RichardHermanson. This helped a lot. The code worked.

Comment: +1 @Richard Hermanson can you add it with next Fullcalendar update?

Comment: I'm not satisfied with the current state of the extension. I've tried to ask arshaw about how to improve it but he hasn't replied yet :(