# Fullcalendar agendaWeek/Day events titles display vertically

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

I want to display vertical text in a FullCalendar event, like this:
[image: picture]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Potentially related: [Full Calendar Week Display Vertical View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376681/full-calendar-week-display-vertical-view)

Comment: agendaWeek is required for me

Comment: try this: https://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-text

Comment: See a very good solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112606/fullcalendar-io-how-to-display-one-event-per-line-in-agendaweek-then-mix-all-in/44246084#44246084).